# Why i am getting "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter x" when i pass parameter value as null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Action method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSearchRequestOperation(SearchRequestModelDto data)
{
     //..
}
```

when I us this url string `http://localhost:9124/Search/SearchRequest?searchRequestFor=0` , it works. but when i use the url `http://localhost:9124/Search/SearchRequest?searchRequestFor=` , it is throwing this exception

> System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'searchRequestFor' of non-nullable type
>   'xxxx.Shared.Dto.Process.Search.SearchRequestFor' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   SearchRequest(xxxx.Shared.Dto.Process.Search.SearchRequestFor)' in
>   'xxxx.WebServer.UI.Controllers.SearchController

if the user is giving second url it should take the value 0.

I tried changing the maproute like below, but that also is not working.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Default1", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Dashboard", id = 0 } 
        );
```

Here is the SearchRequestModelDto class

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchRequestModelDto : UIBoundDto
{
    public SearchRequestModelDto()
    {
        Criteria = new SearchRequestCriteriaDto();
        SearchResult = new SearchRequestResultDto();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public SearchRequestCriteriaDto Criteria { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SearchRequestResultDto SearchResult { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could make the `SearchRequestFor` property on your `SearchRequestModelDto` view model a nullable integer if you want to be able to send null values in the query string:

```
public int? SearchRequestFor { get; set; }
```

The fact that you have set `id=0` in your route has no influence on query string parameters. They are not governed by routes so you will have to either write a custom model binder or use a nullable integer on the model. The latter is preferred.

Comment: The above solution is not working still i am getting the same exception. i will add the SearchRequestModelDto class definition above.

Comment: The SearchRequestCriteriaDto and SearchRequestResultDto  contains lot of properties in both int and int? types.
Is those int properties causing the problem.

Comment: The `SearchRequestModelDto` that you have posted doesn't seem to contain a `SearchRequestFor` integer property so can't possibly work. I guess you haven't shown your real code or the actual request you are sending.

Comment: even SearchRequestFor integer property is not making any difference, so i removed it to show the original class definition.

Comment: You have removed it but then what's the point of using it in a query string then: `http://localhost:9124/Search/SearchRequest?searchRequestFor=0`? Also I guess that when you removed it the error you are getting is different. What is it? Which property does it complain about?

Comment: Thanks for 'Opening my eyes !' , i was looking at wrong action result. we have multiple ajax actions on a page so i missed the faulty one.

Answer (score 0):

This was because the SearchRequestFor type should be nullable

```
public ActionResult SearchRequest(SearchRequestFor? searchRequestFor)
{
    //...
}
```